# Drones location Beacons over 2.4GHz, flight ID regulation

Tags: flight-controller, dji, transmitter-protocol

Two Questions:

First one: Does the general use drones (like DJI products) are mandatory regulated to transmit its location & control's location or Drone ID as beacon over Wi-Fi, BLE or SDR link?

Second question: also by regulation, can a drone fly with flight planner using GPS locations only without transmitting anything back to the controller?

Why I am asking. We have some airfield and needs to detect any nearby drones.

Comment: This will be different in every country. Which country are you asking about?

Comment: @RobinBennett, south sudan